# Magento 1.9 How to applied coupon code automatic

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, automation

Am using **magento 1.9** here am creating a two `coupon code` those are following

1. `SE50`
2. `SE00`

**This is my query:**

I would like to applied `SE50` default in `checkout/cart` page.

how can i do this...?

If it is possible please help me...!